# Cannot get bootstrap button to align center when working with href

Tags: button, twitter-bootstrap

If I remove the  tag the button aligns perfectly but it doesn't link. I've tried multiple combinations with the anchors and no success. Please help.

NOT ALIGNING MIDDLE:

```
<div class="span12" style="text-align:center">
    <a href="mailto:partnerships@medicaldoctorapps.com">
      <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Contact us to get started</button>
    </a>
</div>
```

ALIGNS MIDDLE FINE BUT NO LINK OUT:

```
<div class="span12" style="text-align:center">
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Contact us to get started</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

You must have some other CSS conflicting, take a look here with no CSS they both look fine (http://jsfiddle.net/4kZ3p/). Have you used inspect element (https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements)? its a handy tool when debugging CSS.

Look in the css for the A tag.

-Ken

Needed to add this code to get the jsfiddle to submit but its just your code from above:

```
<div class="span12" style="text-align:center">
   <a href="mailto:partnerships@medicaldoctorapps.com">
      <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Contact us to get started</button>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="span12" style="text-align:center">
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Contact us to get started</button>
</div>
```

Comment: my .centered-pills had a float:left, change this to `float:center` and it works now. thanks all.

Comment: I would reccomend float:none, float:center is not valid css. also you should accept an answer if one was helpful

Answer (score 2):

Insead of Span use the default col classes of Bootstrap.

```
   <div class="col-lg-12" style="text-align:center">                   
                        <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Contact us to get started</button>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Bootstrap 4:

```
<div class="col-12 text-center">
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="mailto:partnerships@medicaldoctorapps.com">Contact us to get started</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

as Ken Koch said, you may have conflict. If you test with Google chrome right click the button, inspect element and select the  "a" tag to see how it's affected by css

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bootstrap just use `<a class = "btn btn-large btn-primary">`

And here's a fiddle that works for me.
http://jsfiddle.net/HAsPV/

Comment: `<div class="span12" style="text-align:center">
  <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="mailto:partnerships@medicaldoctorapps.com">Contact us to get started</a>
</div>` <br/>does not work as well.

Comment: @GiuseppeMigliuri Does it work in the fiddle for you? Or is it just not working for your site?

Comment: @GiuseppeMigliuri Do you have any custom css to go with bootstrap? All that's in the fiddle is bootstrap.min.css directly off their site. If you do have custom, look over it and make sure there's nothing conflicting.

Comment: my .centered-pills had a float:left, change this to float:center and it works now. thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

To bring center the text, you can use `col-md-offset-3` (number can be used according to the need it helps).

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default center-block">Centered Button</button>
```